# Multiplying corresponding entries in lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lists of probabilities and scores:

```
prob = {0.000231743, 0.00386238, 0.0269079, 0.10128, 0.222616, 0.290203, 0.222616, 0.10128, 0.0269079, 0.00386238, 0.000231743}

scores = {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.}
```

By what procedure can I multiply corresponding entries in the two lists and then sum the resulting products to obtain the expected value?

Comment: `Total[prob scores]`?

Comment: I suggest taking the dot product: `prob . scores`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just a scalar product:

```
prob.scores
(* 5. *)
```